# MongoDB: Do I need to store data twice, or can I use extra indexing?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a mongo DB that stores playlist_ids (PID) and song_ids (SID) from Spotify. I currently have documents that have:

1) PID's as the _id field and a list of SID's within the document.

2) SID's as the _id field and a list of PID's they occur in.

It seems redundent to me, as I could (slowly) query all the SID's to get all the SID's for a given PID.  Is there a way to more efficiently perform this two-way lookup without having to store redundant data, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd treat this the same way that I'd treat a `pid_sid` relationship table in a relational database: I'd store individual documents (`{_id, pid, sid}`) for each relationship between PIDs and SIDs, and create 2 indexes: `{pid: 1, sid: 1}` and `{sid: 1, pid: 1}`.

That way, your queries can be answered using only the index (if you specify the correct projection options), data is stored in a single spot and the database does the work to keep the indexes in sync.